# NSDate to NSString returns nil

Tags: nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
 NSString *dateString = @"13-8-06 10:53:54 +0300";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm 'ZZ'"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    // voila!
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

dateFromString is nil. Does anyone know which format should I give to NSDateFormatter??

Comment: I have also tried yy-MM-dd HH:mm ZZ without any result

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *dateString = @"13-8-06 10:53:54 +0300";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *date =[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
dateString =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set date format as

```
@"dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *dateString = @"13-8-06 10:53:54 +0300";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yy-M-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ"];`